# Laravel 5.5 socialite not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.5

I recently tried to integrate laravel socialite with laravel 5.5 but i was getting an error :

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400) Client error: `GET
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me?
>   access_token=$my_token&appsecret_proof=my_proofsecret` resulted in a
>   `400 Bad  Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Error validating
>   access token: Session   has expired on Tuesday, 03-Oct-17 05:00:00
>   PDT. The current (truncated...)

Now i have debugged it to some extent and basically this is the line creating the error in `FacebookProvider.php line number 89`:

```
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $meUrl = $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/me?access_token='.$token.'&fields='.implode(',', $this->fields);

    if (! empty($this->clientSecret)) {
        $appSecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $this->clientSecret);
        $meUrl .= '&appsecret_proof='.$appSecretProof;
    }

    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get($meUrl, [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

this is the line :

```
  $appSecretProof = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $this->clientSecret);
```

If i comment it out this whole if else block it seems to work fine, cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: are you able to login if you remove that line? and is your token is valid? coz it is the error that appears when wrong token or credentials are passed.

Comment: actually i was using the different APP secret code. oops

Comment: is it working properly now?

Comment: yup its working perfectly now.. my bad

Comment: post your answer I will upvote it :)

Comment: done @Mr.Pyramid

Answer (score 1):

I was actually not selecting the access_token's for my application while getting it from the graph API. I selected the default graph api token. Facebook actually lets you generate access token specific to your App so you have to selection it specifically.. Here is a screenshot of it.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

$meUrl .= '&appsecret_proof='.$appSecretProof;

please remove this line and & sign